# gcc-4.7 with Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: linux, gcc, debian

I use debian 8 Jessie, which has only gcc-4.9 available in the repositories. I tried to install gcc-4.7 in two ways without success.

#### First try

I tried installing gcc manually by downloading the file gcc-4.7.0.tar.gz
But when I install the dependency libraries (apt-get install Libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp-dev gcc-multilib)
the Debian installs, without asking gcc-4.9 and the compatible libraries with gcc-4.9. 
I try run make for manual installation, but errors occur and it is not possible to install manually.

#### Second Try

I tried adding PPA repositories with gcc-4.7, in the file /etc/apt/sourc.list
Add-apt-repository ppa: ubuntu-toolchain-r / test as it teaches in this Link: https://askubuntu.com/questions/193513/problem-adding-a-ppa-to-install-gcc-4-7

When try apt-get install gcc-4.7 you are prompted to install several Dependencies ... when requesting to install the dependencies, the Below.

---

```
Root @ vmhp110deb8: / home / user1 # apt-get install gcc-4.7 gcc-4.7-base
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
Note, by selecting 'gcc-4.7-base' for regex 'gcc-4.7'
Package gcc-4.7-base is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
Is available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.7-base' has no installation candidate
Root @ vmhp110deb8: / home / user1 # add-apt-repository ppa: ubuntu-toolchain-r / test
```

---

I tried to find a repository that has gcc-4.7-base, but then it asks Installation of other dependencies, and informs that it has not found
Libraries are Obsolete, etc.

#### Attempt not yet tested

Another idea that i had is download the Debian 7 Wheezy DVD (which I think Which has gcc-4.7 and all dependencies) and add as repository, For debian to find all dependencies of gcc.4.7 on DVD. But this idea i not have tested yet.

Could anyone help me with how I could install gcc 4.7 on debian 8?

Comment: This [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165889/debian-jessie-why-gcc-4-7-conflicts-with-gcc-4-8/165891#165891) may help.

Comment: If you don't have Ubuntu installed, why do you think adding an Ubuntu-specific hack is a good idea?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [unix.se]. Though gcc is obviously used in programming, questions about how to install it aren't really programming questions; they could apply to *any* package you're having trouble installing. (If nothing else, you can build it from source.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

As you can read here 
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=765379

gcc-4.7 is not included in Debian Jessie

Maybe you can try this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.7
```

EDIT : You already tries this. I didnt notice.

Try this manual: 
http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/

I hope this helps to you :)